# .NET 3.5 Chart Controls Disabled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I've been using .NET 4.0 C# Windows Form Application utilizing the chart controls to render a chart on my form. I've recently had to switch to .NET 3.5 to use a reference that doesn't support 4.0. Now, I can’t use the chart controls for my application.
I’ve downloaded and installed the recommended packages:

Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14422

Microsoft Chart Controls Add-on for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23903

But my problem is that I am using Visual Studio 2010, the add-on is only for vs2008.

I had to select 'Show All' on the toolbox in order to even see the chart option, but now it is disabled and when I attempt to click and drag I get a error icon as my mouse pointer.
I tried to upload the image that shows the disabled chart, but SO wouldnt let me.

Is there any way that I can use the .Net 3.5 Chart Controls with VS2010?

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: have you tried to change the Project Properties of the output from a 4.0 project to a 3.5 project for starters

Comment: There are very few cases where a 4.0 application cannot reference a 3.5 assembly since said assembly will run in CLR2 compatability mode. Are you sure you can't use 4.0?

Comment: I have changed the project properties to 3.5.

Comment: I'm not having any trouble with it.  Beware that there are multiple controls named "Chart".  It will end up in the "Data" group in the toolbox if you target 4.0.  But not if you target 3.5

Comment: hmm, I am not familiar with CLR2 compatability mode. But when I run in 4.0 I get this     

"Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface."

Through my internet research I found to change the target framework. When I changed it no longer gave the error.

Comment: I can see the chart control under the data group in the toolbox, but it is disabled.

Comment: The Chart control does not use COM.  Clearly you've got the wrong one selected, probably the Office one.

Comment: The COM error message has nothing to do with the Chart. Only to the reference I'm using, which is why is switched to 3.5

Comment: I've now done this on two different computers, and have had the same result.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click into toolbox
2. choose items...
3. filter for "chart"
4. check out chart-checkboxes

Now they should be available.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded to framework 4.0, remove manually added references of chart control, because framework 4 already has chart control.

Comment: not relevant - question says "I've recently had to switch to .NET 3.5 to use a reference that doesn't support 4.0. "

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project|Application properties and change your target framework to .NET Framework 4.  It will close the solution and reopen it by itself. your chart control will be enabled.

Comment: not relevant - question says "I've recently had to switch to .NET 3.5 to use a reference that doesn't support 4.0. "

Answer (score 0):

This is how I included chart in .net 3.5. Download the dll from "https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/". You can check the license there. Now open visual studio/visual c# express(In my case it is Visual C# express 2008). Go to Tools->Choose ToolBox Items-> In the window there would be a "browse" button in the bottom side. Browse the downloaded dll. Now it will show the "Chart" control in the same window's ".Net Framework Components" tab.Now click on it and press "OK". Now go to your toolbox , there you can find the "Chart" Control.